# Username Availability Check using AJAX and PHP against MSSQL

Tags: php, ajax, sql-server-2008

I have a database already full of clients. We are trying to let them setup online access. They must provide their member ID to set up their online account. I have built a test form that allows input to memberid and should check to see if we find them in the database. I have pulled my hair out trying to get this to work. I have also made CRUD so I know my connection to MSSQL is working.

What is wrong with this code?

FORM

```
<div class="container">
<div>Member ID: <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="uname" id="uname" /><span id="status"></span></div>
<div>Pass: <input type="password" maxlength="10" name="pwd" id="pwd" /></div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("uname").onblur = function() {
var xmlhttp;
var uname=document.getElementById("uname");
if (uname.value != "")
    {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
        };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","uname_availability.php?uname="+encodeURIComponent(uname.value),true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
};
</script>
```

And Here is uname_availability.php

```
<?php
$uname=$_REQUEST['uname'];

$server = "serveraddress";
$user = "username";
$pwd = "password";
$db = "dbname";

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, array("UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$pwd, "Database"=>$db));

if($conn === false){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblMembership WHERE MemberID = ".$uname."";
$stmt3 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt3);
if ($row_count === false)
{
print "<span style=\"color:red;\">We Can Not Find You :(</span>";
}
else
{
print "<span style=\"color:green;\">We Found You :)  </span>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You haven't said what the actual problem is. Does your code give the wrong results, or no results, or an error? And please always use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: May I ask why you aren't using Jquery? Using it will make your life much easier. Also, what exactly is happening? Is it always coming back true or not getting to the if statement at all?

Comment: @Pondlife It always shows "We Can Not Find You :(" even if the memberID exists. I have even tried hard coding the memberID into the select statement like this - SELECT * FROM tblMembership WHERE MemberID = 7990 and it still shows "We Can Not Find You :("

Comment: @zazvorniki yes i should use jQuery. This is just something i am testing with and it should work. It is always coming back false.

Comment: Have you tried using a empty() instead of if ($row_count === false)

Comment: And does the same query return results in SSMS or when run with sqlcmd? If you're sure that you're connecting to the correct database and that you don't have two `tblMembership` tables in different schemas (you should always include the schema name in queries), you could use SQL Profiler to see what the SQL actually being executed on the server is. Your double quotes look a little odd, but I don't know anything about PHP.

Comment: @Pondlife yes i have ran the query against the database and get results

Comment: @zazvorniki just tried if (empty($row_count)) with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting it with this...thanks for all the input...I really appreciate it all!

```
$sql = "SELECT MemberID FROM tblMembership WHERE MemberID = '".$memid."'";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
$row = sqlsrv_fetch($stmt);
if (empty($row))
{
print "<span style=\"color:red;\">We Can Not Find You >:-(</span>";
}
else
{
print "<span style=\"color:green;\">We Found You :-)  </span>";
}
```

Comment: i also changed the var $uname to $memid

Answer (score 0):

Your query is failing, because you've failed to quote your $username parameter, leading to both incorrect and invalid SQL, and an [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblMembership WHERE MemberID = '".$uname."'";
                                                     ^--        ^--
```

without the quotes, you're doing `WHERE MemberID = fred`, and I highly doubt you've got a `fred` field in your membership table.

Since your code blindly assumes the query is working correct, you will never ever see the syntax error warnings that SQL server **WILL HAVE** been providing.

Comment: I have just changed this to: $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblMembership WHERE MemberID = '".$uname."'"; and still get negative result :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to quote the value of your parameter in your SQL statement ?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblMembership WHERE MemberID = ".$uname."";
```

would then become

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblMembership WHERE MemberID = '".$uname."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you explicitly use `$_GET`,

```
if(isset($_GET['uname']))
{
  $uname=$_GET['uname'];
}
```

And then query like,

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblMembership WHERE MemberID ='$uname'";
```